# Difficulty With Multiple VHosts on EC2 Instance

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I admit my knowledge of VirtualHosts can be cursory, but I'm taking on a task that I am struggling with.  I will need to have two domains reaching two different folders on my EC2 instance; let's call them *domaina.com* and *domainb.com*.

I have set up my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file like so;

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/domaina/www/html"
    ServerName "domaina.com"
    ServerName "www.domaina.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/domainb/www/html"
    ServerName "domainb.com"
    ServerName "www.domainb.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

Upon updating this, I have restarted Apache using the `sudo service httpd restart` command.

As far as I can tell, `domaina.com` is working without issue.  It is loading the website hosted at /var/domaina/www/html.  However, visiting `domainb.com` routes me to domaina.com's website.  Instead of routing to /var/domainb/www/html, it seems to be routing to /var/domaina/www/html/.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/domaina/www/html"
    ServerName "domaina.com"
    ServerAlias "www.domaina.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/domainb/www/html"
    ServerName "domainb.com"
    ServerAlias "www.domainb.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

The `ServerName` directive may appear anywhere within the definition of a VirtualHost. However, each appearance overrides the previous appearance (within that VirtualHost). Your `ServerName "domainb.com"` was overridden by `ServerName "www.domainb.com"`. After that, since there was no match for hostname `domainb.com`, the default `VirtualHost` was used, and that is the top one.

Comment: This definitely got me way further than anything else - Thank you!  Using your approach, I can access the contents of `/var/domaina/www/html` by going to `domaina.com`.  With that said, when I visit `domainb.com`, it's taking me to an Apache Test Page, even though `/var/domainb/www/html` has a full site and index.html file.  Not sure why `domainb.com` is not leading me to the correct file, though it does seem to be recognizing the Virtual Host properly now.

Comment: Well, your shown configuration is very simple and there is nothing much that can go wrong there... you can 1) check for any other `DocumentRoot` directives in other `.conf` files 2) check for any `.htaccess` file in domainb root folder 3) check for anything strange in errorlog